# MySQL How do I flatten out the results into one row with out getting a NULL

Tags: mysql

I'm very new to MySQL queries and can't figure out how to get the data to look the way I want.

I have three tables that generally look like this but with a lot more data and the final query will not be restricted by one hostname that I have here.  I'm just trying to simplify it.

infrastructure_server table

```
id | hostname
1    ld0007
```

infrastructure_server_jobs table

```
server_id  |  job_id
1             1
1             2
```

jobs_job table

```
id  |  end_date
1      2015-12-21 09:51:56
2      2016-01-27 10:02:36
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN type = "provision" THEN CAST(end_date AS DATE) END AS ProvDate,
    CASE WHEN type = "decom" THEN CAST(end_date AS DATE) END AS DecomDate,
    infserver.hostname as HostName

FROM 
    infrastructure_server infserver

inner join infrastructure_server_jobs sj on infserver.id = sj.server_id
inner join jobs_job jj on sj.job_id = jj.id

where
infserver.status != "PROVFAILED"
AND
infserver.group_id ="2"
AND
infserver.hostname ="ld0007"
```

My results are:

```
ProvDate, DecomDate, HostName
'2015-12-21', NULL, 'ld0007'
NULL, '2016-01-27', 'ld0007'
```

If I add a group by HostName then it flattens it out into one row but I lose the DecomDate:

```
ProvDate, DecomDate, HostName
'2015-12-21', NULL, 'ld0007'
```

What I need the results to be is one row per hostname:

```
ProvDate, DecomDate, HostName
'2015-12-21', '2016-01-27', 'ld0007'
```

Thorsten, the column type is in jobs_job table.  The tool I'm using is MySQl Workbench.  If I run the query with out the MAX() (in the original post and remove the infserver.hostname = 'ld0007' here are some of the rows I get back

```
ProvDate, DecomDate, HostName
'2016-01-28', NULL, 'ld0043'
NULL, '2016-01-29', 'ld0043'
'2016-01-28', NULL, 'ld0044'
NULL, '2016-03-30', 'ld0044'
'2016-01-28', NULL, 'ld0045'
NULL, '2016-03-30', 'ld0045'
'2016-01-28', NULL, 'ld0046'
NULL, '2016-01-28', 'ld0046'
'2016-01-28', NULL, 'ld0047'
NULL, '2016-01-29', 'ld0047'
'2016-01-29', NULL, 'ld0048'
NULL, '2016-03-14', 'ld0048'
'2016-01-29', NULL, 'ld0049'
NULL, '2016-02-09', 'ld0049'
'2016-01-29', NULL, 'ld0050'
NULL, '2016-03-31', 'ld0050'
'2016-01-29', NULL, 'ld0051'
NULL, '2016-01-29', 'ld0051'
'2016-01-29', NULL, 'ld0052'
NULL, '2016-01-29', 'ld0052'
'2016-01-29', NULL, 'ld0053'
NULL, '2016-01-29', 'ld0053'
```

If I add a counter to it I get back a total of 1989 rows.  When I add the MAX() I only get back one record

```
SET @counter = 0;
SELECT
    (@counter:= @counter + 1) as counter,
    CASE WHEN type = "provision" THEN CAST(end_date  AS DATE) END AS ProvDate,
    CASE WHEN type = "decom" THEN CAST(end_date AS DATE) END AS DecomDate,
    infserver.hostname as HostName
FROM 
    infrastructure_server infserver
inner join infrastructure_server_jobs sj on infserver.id = sj.server_id
inner join jobs_job jj on sj.job_id = jj.id
where
infserver.status != "PROVFAILED"
AND
infserver.group_id ="2"
```

Comment: What table is column `type` in?

Comment: Yes, aggregate functions, such as `MAX` aggregate your rows to one result row. If you want one result row per hostname, then group by hostname as shown in the answers.

Comment: Thank you I just realized I was missing that in my query.  It's working!!!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When grouping by hostname, you get one result row per hostname. If you select ProvDate for instance, you get one ProvDate hence - as long as you don't specify which. So use an aggregation function such as `MAX` to say which one you want to get. And as `MAX` ignores nulls, this even solves your whole problem :-)

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'provision' THEN CAST(end_date AS DATE) END) AS ProvDate,
  MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'decom' THEN CAST(end_date AS DATE) END) AS DecomDate,
  infserver.hostname as HostName
FROM infrastructure_server infserver
INNER JOIN infrastructure_server_jobs sj on infserver.id = sj.server_id
INNER JOIN jobs_job jj on sj.job_id = jj.id
where infserver.status <> 'PROVFAILED'
AND infserver.group_id = 2
AND infserver.hostname = 'ld0007'
group by infserver.hostname;
```